# Heat transfer and thermal energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Some hot water radiators have a single pipe connected to them. The steam comes to the radiator and the water leaves in the same pipe. The steam and the water are both at a temperature of 100°C. Where does the heat come from?

Comment: latent heat of vaporization/condensation of water at 100C: $2.26[kJ/g]$

Answer (score 2):

from the phase transition from vapor to liquid. Even if at the same temperature, you require energy to tranform water at 100C into vapor at 100C. And the reverse is also true.